# DrawerLayout падает с IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Начались падения приложения. Заметил, что падает на строке: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_servers);`

Вот logcat:

> 07-07 14:34:29.854  24246-24246/ux.uchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:831)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
>               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2191)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15609)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

В самом XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="ux.uchat.UChat">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/android">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="ux.uchat.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: что насчет расстановки открывающих скобок `<` Их хватает в начале и в конце

Comment: Я их убрал потамучто stackoverflow.com их убирает, и студия бы не позволила скомпилировать.

Comment: Оно вам говорит, что не может вычислить размеры виджета. Есть мнение, что `DrawerLayout` не воспринимает размеры `wrap_content`. Попробуйте заменить на `match_parent`

Comment: О спасибо, заработало, я уже думал стирать активность:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стэктрейсе написано, что невозможно вычислить размеры виджета `DrawerLayout`.

Есть мнение, что `DrawerLayout` не воспринимает размеры `wrap_content`. Укажите размеры виджета `match_parent`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parrent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- другие виджеты -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```